# STDOUT: CMake Error: No source or binary directory provided - Kivy Buildozer

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmake, kivy, buildozer

I get the

```
STDOUT: CMake Error: No source or binary directory provided
```

when I try to compile my kivy buildozer app with CMake 3.13.3 installed.

How to fix that error?

I'm currently using python 2, kivy complete VM 0.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like an application uses an undocumented feature of `cmake` executable to work without source and binary directories specified in the command line.

In CMake 3.13.3 this feature has been "fixed" in accordance to documentation.

There is an [issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/18817) in CMake bugtracker, where they find that "fixing" the feature breaks some applications. So they decide to emit a warning instead. The warning (instead of the error) has been implemented in CMake 3.13.4.